# JSON breaking with quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting a Broken JSON, with quotes inside quotes. I can't convert it, because of the error;

```
{
 "PENDENCIA": "Whatever",
 "RESULTADO": "Teste "blabla"."
}
```

Comment: `{
 "PENDENCIA": "Whatever",
 "RESULTADO": "Teste \"blabla\"."
}`

Comment: Either escape the double quote with `\` or use single quotes around it.

Comment: Just escape your quotes with "\", like `"Teste \"blabla\"."`

Comment: Use a proper library to generate the JSON. That will take care of properly escaping the data.

Comment: But I already receive JSON like this, I can't edit the place of origin

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is how to "escape" characters in JSON. Because JSON uses quotes around all of the string values ("Whatever"), you can't just include a quote inside your string -- there's no way JSON can figure out that "Teste " isn't the full string but instead should be continued until the final ".

You will need to rewrite the JSON to be "Teste \"blabla\"."

If the JSON is being automatically generated, you'll need to fix whatever is generating your JSON.

Comment: But I already receive JSON like this, I can't edit the place of origin

Comment: TL/DR: you have to write fixup code.

To be precise: what you're getting isn't JSON. It's 100% the job of the provider to send you correctly formatted data. -- indeed, one of the best lessons any programmer can get is the ability to get their providers to send correct data.

In the meanwhile, you you'll need to write custom code to convert the incoming data to JSON. This is nasty, fiddly unplanned work that will hurt your schedule. It will also be delicate and will break every time your unreliable providers fiddle with their own code.